# Etymology of 武蔵

Tags: kanji, etymology, ateji

What is the etymology of the old province and Japanese name 武蔵?

[Wikipedia claims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musashi_Province) that it is non-Yamato vocabulary from an Ainu language. Even if this is true, why were these characters (military/weapon + store) chosen as ateji?

Comment: Japanese wikipedia has a full explanation: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A6%E8%94%B5%E5%9B%BD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Etymology

There are numerous theories about this.

**Japanese:**

- The theories restricted to Japanese origins all revolve around the ideas of some larger geographic area that was split into "upper" (*-kami* or *-gami*) and "lower" (*-shimo*) halves.  The main theories listed at [the JA Wikipedia article on 武蔵国](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A6%E8%94%B5%E5%9B%BD) (*Musashi no Kuni*) and at [the Nihon Jiten page here](http://nihonjiten.com/data/115152.html) revolve around an ancient province named *Musa* or *Munza* (or possibly even *Fusa*).  After the ostensible split, there would have been *Musa-gami* and *Musa-shimo*, and the theory goes that the name *Musa-gami* lost the leading *mu* to become *Sagami*, while *Musa-shimo* lost the trailing *mo* to become *Musashi*.
  → This seems a little strained and unlikely, however.

Other theories look beyond just Japanese for the origins of the name, and find possibilities in Ainu, as mentioned in [the EN Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musashi_Province#cite_ref-2), and maybe even Korean, as mentioned in [the Nihon Jiten entry](http://nihonjiten.com/data/115152.html).

**Ainu:**

- Per [Vovin's paper](http://shikon.nichibun.ac.jp/dspace/handle/123456789/1482) mentioned in the EN Wikipedia article: Japanese *musashi*, from older *muzashi*, from yet older *munzashi*, from Ainu *mun* ("grass, weeds") *sa* ("open, exposed; a plain, a wide-open area") *-hi* (third-person possessive suffix), with Ainu *hi* becoming Japanese *shi* (as observed in other likely terms).  So *mun* *sa-hi* would ostensibly mean "grassy or weedy plain".
  → This holds together reasonably well.  However, I cannot find any mention of this *-hi* possessive suffix in [Batchelor's seminal Ainu dictionary](https://archive.org/details/ainuenglishjapan00batcuoft).  I do find another *-hi*, used as a nominalizing suffix for verbs and adjectives.  I also see mention of *-i*, again used as a nominalizing suffix for verbs and adjectives.  This is also used to indicate demonstrative pronouns, and to indicate direction to or from a place.
  I find this gap in Vovin's etymology rather odd, especially as the paper explicitly cites Batchelor's dictionary as the source for the Ainu word *sa*, and as Batchelor's work also lists Ainu *mun* as "grass, weeds" in agreement with Vovin's etymology.
- Per [the Nihon Jiten entry](http://nihonjiten.com/data/115152.html), Japanese *musashi*, then probably from much older possible *mushashi* (see **Spelling** below), from Ainu *mo* ("sluggish, quiet, gentle") *casi* ("fort, castle; enclosure", where Ainu *ca* is read similarly to Japanese ちゃ).
  → This doesn't seem very likely.

**Korean:**

- Per [the Nihon Jiten entry](http://nihonjiten.com/data/115152.html), マル (probably [말 *mal*, "great"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%A7%90#Etymology_4)) + チャチ (probably 차지 *chaji*, part of compound verb [차지하다 *chaji-hada* "to hold, occupy, take, have"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%B0%A8%EC%A7%80%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4)), together meaning something like "great holding, great occupation".
  → This theory also seems unlikely.

**Conclusion:**

We don't know where *musashi* really comes from, or what it might have originally meant.  All the theories I've read so far have holes in them, and none seem conclusive.  From my personal perspective, Vovin's Ainu derivation seems the closest to convincing, but that hypothesized final *-hi* remains unexplained.

### Spelling

From the JA Wikipedia article, specifically the section at https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A6%E8%94%B5%E5%9B%BD#.E5.9B.BD.E5.90.8D (my additions in [square brackets]):

> 表記については、飛鳥京・藤原宮木簡に「无耶志国」と見え、7世紀頃までの武蔵は「无射志」(ムザシ)や「牟射志」(ムンザシ)と表記されていた記録も見つかっている[1]。他にも「牟佐志[2]」、「無邪志[3]」といったの表記があるが、いずれも訓に字を当てたものと考えられている。
>     For the spelling, we find 无耶志国 [probably *mu ya shi kuni*, maybe *mu sha shi kuni*] in the Asuka wooden fragments [see [this EN Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB#Mokkan) for more], and there are also records that show spellings of 无射志 (*muzashi*) and 牟射志 (*munzashi*) until around the 7th century.  Additional spellings include 牟佐志 and 無邪志, but all of these are thought to be reading-based *ateji*.

As for your specific question, "*why were these characters (military/weapon + store) chosen as ateji*", I have not yet found any sources stating specific reasons, though presumably the use of 武 had something to do with the military importance of the area.

Comment: More on *-(h)i*: http://catalog.lib.kyushu-u.ac.jp/handle/2324/8607/scs04p099.pdf

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I'm not entirely sold on Vovin's proposition there; if *-i* still presents as *-i*, which it does in other cases, I fail to see the mechanism by which *a* + *-i* = *aa*, *u* + *-i* = *uu*, etc. It seems more likely that the possessive maybe originated from just *-h* instead, manifesting as a stronger stress on the vowel or a longer vowel to make it more clearly heard. *a* + *-h* = *aa* or *aha*, etc. seems phonologically easier to account for. Be that as it may, the expected possessive for a noun ending in *a* would be *aa* or *aha*, ruling out *mun sa **hi***.